# Unity Nested FOR loops Bug

Tags: unity, maze

I'm writing a script to randomly generate a maze, and I can't even get it off the ground, rip. I've written fractal generators so I'm no stranger to nested FOR loops. `FOR x{ FOR y }`
I'm using my same old tricks to generate the maze. To initialize it, I set the boundary of the Maze (NESW sides) to be walls like so:

```
// Create
List<Room> row = new List<Room>();
for(int i=0; i<width; i++)  // Columns (X-axis)
{   row.Clear();
    for(int j=0; j<depth; j++){ // Rows (Z-axis)
        row.Add(new Room(i, yOffset, j));

        if(i==width-1){ Debug.Log("SetE: i "+i+", j "+j);
        row[j].setE(-1); }
        if(i==0){ Debug.Log("SetW: i "+i+", j "+j);
        row[j].setW(-1); }
    }
    row[width-1].setN(-1);
    row[0].setS(-1);
    rooms.Add(row);
}
// Instantiate
for(int i=0; i<width; i++) for(int j=0; j<depth; j++)
{   // Room
    Instantiate(roomGO, new Vector3(i + transform.position.x,
                           yOffset, j + transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
    // North Side
    Instantiate(getWall(rooms[i][j],0), new Vector3(i + transform.position.x,
                                           yOffset, j + transform.position.z + .75f), transform.rotation);
    // East Side
    Instantiate(getWall(rooms[i][j],1), new Vector3(i + transform.position.x + .75f,
                                           yOffset, j + transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
    // South Side
    Instantiate(getWall(rooms[i][j],2), new Vector3(i + transform.position.x,
                                           yOffset, j + transform.position.z - .75f), transform.rotation);
    // West Side
    Instantiate(getWall(rooms[i][j],3), new Vector3(i + transform.position.x - .75f,
                                           yOffset, j + transform.position.z), transform.rotation);
}
```

My problem is here (*I think), Lines 7 to 10:

```
if(i==width-1){ Debug.Log("SetE: i "+i+", j "+j);
    row[j].setE(-1); }
if(i==0){ Debug.Log("SetW: i "+i+", j "+j);
    row[j].setW(-1); }
```

The positions are correct. I have no problems with the North and South sides.
The Western walls are not Instantiating. But the Eastern walls are Instantiating on every single row?
I'm trying to set all the West and East walls of the rooms with Coords `(x=0/x=Width, z)`. The `Debug.Log` lines are printing the expected coordinates.

**Question**
Why aren't the Eastern and Western walls Instantiating properly? What is a better way to set the walls of my Maze?

Comment: "Is this Unity, C#, my Code, or my Computer?" Always assume it's your code. If there were a flaw in Unity or your computer so fundamental that they couldn't properly navigate a for loop, your computer would fail to boot, and no game would have ever shipped on the engine. So "this is someone else's fault" is not a plausible explanation here.

Comment: What exactly is `rooms`? You're using a single instantiation for `row`. `row` gets cleared at the top of the first loop & added to `rooms` at the bottom. Unless `rooms.Add(row)` is making a deep copy (which wouldn't be my assumption) this looks like the steps of iteration n will always be wiping out the work of iteration n-1.

Comment: @Pikalek ```rooms``` is a nested list (```List<List<>>```). What I'm trying to do create a sort of "Dumby" ```List<>``` and copy-paste it (so to speak) into the elements of ```rooms```. Hence, first I clear ```row```, then fill it, then add it, repeat. Weird thing is NS is completely unaffected by this.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix, the bug is not in lines 7 to 10 like I thought. Rather, because I'm adding the same instance of the List `row`, Clearing it, and adding it repeatedly, the rows get a little buggy. My fault for not seeing this.
Instead of `rooms.Add(row)`, I should have been using `rooms.Add(new List<Room>(row))`. This way, when I dump `row`, I still have the data stored in `rooms`.
*Special thanks to @DMGregory and @Pikalek*

Comment: You may want to use .ToArray once you're done filling a row and know its final size, since you no longer need the dynamic resizing a list gives you. Or you could make the whole thing use a 2D array for better cache locality.